# Эффект toggle для названий и значений атрибутов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте.

Все знакомы с функцией `.toggle()` и `.toggleClass()`, которые изменяют местами стили и классы элемента:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.block').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('block_new-style');
  });
});
```

```css
.block {width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: red}
.block.block_new-style {background-color: green}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="block"></div>
```

Но можно ли как-то заменить таким образом название или значение атрибута?
К примеру:

> Есть элемент `<div class="block" data-style="0"></div>`, при нажатии
>   на него, его значение атрибута `data-style` изменялось на `1` и при
>   повторном нажатии снова на `0`

Или:

> Есть элемент `<div class="block" data-style_0></div>`, при нажатии на
>   него, его название атрибута `data-style_0` изменялось на
>   `data-style_1` и при повторном нажатии снова на `data-style_0`, но при этом если в нём есть какое-то значение, то оно оставалось неизменным

Кто реализовывал такое? Буду очень признателен, если поделитесь своими соображениями. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: _можно ли как-то заменить таким образом_ - таким это каким? Используя функции `toggle` и `toggleClass`? или с помощью написания своей функции?

Comment: @Grundy, написанием своей. Под "таким образом" я имел введу, что бы при повторном нажатии значение возвращалось

Comment: `toggle` и `toggleClass` работают только с двумя возможными значениями: true/false. Как ты хочешь определять какие значения нужно использовать для атрибутов? То есть, почему `data-style="0"` должен замениться на `data-style="1"`? это только единственный возможный случай? или значения в отдельных случаях могут отличаться?

Comment: @Grundy, допустим я создаю функцию и указываю `toggleAttr('название атрибута', 'значение1', 'значение2')`

Comment: под этот вызов никак не попадает _`data-style_0` при нажатии на него, его название атрибута `data-style_0` изменялось на  `data-style_1`_ - что ты будешь передавать в качестве параметра _название_ и что в качестве значений?

Comment: @Grundy, сложный вопрос :D Ну допустим, `data-style0="0"` - синий фон, `data-style0="1"` - красный фон, `data-style1="0"` - длинный блок, а `data-style1="1"` короткий блок

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51872/discussion-between-grundy-and-yuri).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На сколько мне известно, таких функций нет, но:

Если заморочиться, можно замутить свою функцию, которая будет выполнять такие действия. Но при этом будет выглядеть как обычная jQuery-функция:

```js
//пишем функционал:
$.fn.toggleAttr = function(name,value1,value2) {
  this.attr(name, this.attr(name) == value1 ? value2 : value1);
  return this;
};

//тестируем:
$('div').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleAttr('title','Первый','Второй')
  
})
```

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div title='Не установлен'></div>
```

По названию аттрибута

```js
//пишем функционал:
$.fn.toggleAttrName = function(name1,name2) {
  if(this.is('['+name1+']')){
    this.attr(name2,this.attr(name1)).removeAttr(name1)
  }else{
    this.attr(name1,this.attr(name2)).removeAttr(name2)
  }
  return this;
};

//тестируем:
$('div').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleAttrName('data-attr-0','data-attr-1')
  
})
```

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-attr-0='значение'></div>
```

Comment: функция data не меняет значение атрибута

Comment: @Grundy нажмите **выполнить код**, чтобы убедиться, что он работает

Comment: Я не сказал, что код не работает. Я сказал, что _функция data **не меняет значение атрибута**_

Comment: @Grundy это просто пример, хотите менять атрибут - пишите `attr` вместо `data`.

Comment: Атрибут хочет менять автор вопроса, и на данный момент ответ с этой задачей не справляется.

Comment: @Grundy да пожалуйста, непонятно почему пишете вы, а не автор вопроса

Comment: Да, хорошо, значение атрибута меняет на ура. А изменить его название как? Ну что бы атрибут `title="Первый"`превращался, допустим, в `data-title="Первый"`? )

Comment: Неважно кто пишет. Главное чтобы ответ начал отвечать на вопрос

Comment: @Yuri, никак, нельзя менять названия атрибутов, можно удалить один атрибут и добавить второй

Comment: @Grundy, а если я скажу, что можно?) Скажем так: этот вопрос создан, что бы проверить знания и логику пользователей и помочь тем, кому нужно будет это сделать. Ваш вариант с удалением один из правильных, но есть ещё один

Comment: @Yuri, дописал ответ

Comment: @Crantisz, если никто не предложит лучше, приму ваш ответ :)

Comment: @Yuri, хотелось бы увидеть остальные _правильные_. И какой смысл принимать один ответ, если ты знаешь еще несколько? Добавляй свой ответ с хорошими пояснениями. Пока и вопрос и ответы несколько бесполезны.

Comment: @Yuri - сделал смену названия атрибута с сохранением его значения

Comment: @Crantisz, если вы хотите, то добавьте меня в одном из соц. сетей указанных в моём профиле. Покажу функции, которые написал

Answer (score -1):

```
function dataToggle ($el) {
   $el.data('style', $el.data('style')
        ? '0' 
        : '1');
    }

dataToggle ($('.block'));
```

или

```
$('.block').on('click', dataToggle($(this)))
```

Не тестировал, но я бы сделал так

Comment: Вы уж определитесь, `attr` или `data` вы тоглите...

Comment: _функция data не меняет значение атрибута_

Comment: @Grundy учите мат часть, меняет https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/#data1

Comment: @ГошкаТарасов укажите точнее где это там написано.

Comment: @ГошкаТарасов, матчасть, это конечно хорошо, особенно если бы в ней было написано, что меняется _значение атрибута_. На самом деле, значение атрибута используется только при первом чтении. В противном случае значения хранятся во внутреннем объекте и к dom обращения нет. Это можно увидеть в реализации функции [_data_](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.fn.data)

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/data/ первый пример с кодом

Comment: @ГошкаТарасов, и что показывает данный пример? Только то, что работает функция `data`. Но не то, что она меняет атрибут. Ты можешь это проверить просто заглянув в разметку, и увидев, что у `div` к которому должен был добавиться атрибут - ничего не добавилось.

Answer (score -1):

Можно написать функции:

```
function toggleDataAttr (el, name, firstValue, secondValue) {
    if (el.data(name) === firstValue) {
        el.data(name, secondValue); 
    } else {
        el.data(name, firstValue);
    }
}

function toggleAttr (el, name, firstValue, secondValue) {
    if (el.attr(name) === firstValue) {
        el.attr(name, secondValue); 
    } else {
        el.attr(name, firstValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: и как эти функции использовать? что означают параметры? что можно в эти параметры передавать?

Comment: _функция data **не меняет** значение атрибута_

Comment: Простите, но ваша функция не изменяет название атрибута, она создаёт новый атрибут с новым названием

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.